# Database of consumer (food) product ownership

Tags: data-request, food, products, companies

I'd like to find a source of corporate ownership information for consumer products, in particular foods. For example products that have labels/brands which are owned by GlaxoSmithKleine, Monsanto, etc.

Does anyone know of something like this?

Edit:

- I'd just like the companies that produce brands. For example Dasani is produced by Coke, Pringles are owned by P&G. [image: Basically this image].
- As for the format of the data, anything that I can write a script to read is fine. CSV, XML, JSON, SQL, whatever.

Comment: Have you considered looking at UPC and EAN databases? The first few digits indicate the manufacturer. However, the company that assigns the UPC may not always be the company you seek.

Comment: Related: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9378/seeking-a-food-product-taxonomy